# gyp WARN EACCES trying to install angular/cli

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm

I' working with Ubuntu 17.04 and I have installed node 8.9.4LTS. When I try to install angular/cli using npm I get this error in loop.

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '8.9.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.9.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.9.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.9.4
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4
```

Here is a screen capture of the error:

[image]

I try to make the installation with this command: *sudo npm install -g @angular/cli*

How can I install angular CLI?

**Fixed it!!!:**

I don't know why but I have tried to install angular/cli again and it works!!! Previously I don't do anything!!! I don't know what happened!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was good that the problem got solved itself. But a short explanation I want to share with you, that might be helpful to you in future as follows.

It looks like you're running into permission issues. If you are installing `npm-packages` then it might possible that you are getting an `EACCES` error when trying to install a package globally. This means you do not have permission to write to the directories `npm` uses to store global packages and commands.

You can change the directory permissions by running commands: `sudo chmod u+x -R 775 ~/.npm` and `sudo chown $USER -R ~/.npm` or you can just run any `npm` command with `sudo`, that should get resolve your issue.

If you are installing an `npm-package` locally, then you should be in your local project directory and can try running `sudo npm install <pkg-name>` command to install required package. the purpose of using `sudo` is that it will change your owner permissions so you can make your current user authorized to run `npm` commands.

I'd recommend you to take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I try to install the package with sudo because previously I've got an error that told me that it hadn't permission to write in a directory that I don't remember now :( Thank you so much for your explanation